# C# Automapper 6.0.2 Keeps throwing StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, automapper

**Initializing the mapper**

```
public static class MapperConfig
{
    public const int MAX_MAPPING_DEPTH = 2;

    private static MapperConfiguration _config;
    private static IMapper _mapper;
    public static IMapper Mapper => _mapper ?? (_mapper = GetConfig().CreateMapper());

    public static MapperConfiguration GetConfig()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        if (_config != null)
            return _config;

        _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfiles(assembly);
            cfg.ForAllMaps(ConfigTypeMapping);
        });

        _config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return _config;
    }


    public static void ConfigTypeMapping(TypeMap map, IMappingExpression expression)
    {
        map.ShouldCheckForValid();

        expression.PreserveReferences();
        expression.MaxDepth(MAX_MAPPING_DEPTH);
        //expression.ForAllMembers(m => m.UseDestinationValue());
    }
}
```

**The main entity**

```
[ResourceKey("MEDIA_ITEM")]
public class MediaItem : SocialEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     User-defined media item <see cref="Title"/> or its original file name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The original <see cref="FileName"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="FileGuid"/> that refers to the CDN file entry.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid FileGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The purpose / group (aka <see cref="Type"/>) for this <see cref="MediaItem"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public FileType Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows limiting retrieval of this <see cref="MediaItem"/> depending on a specific <see cref="PrivacyLevel"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="Source"/> for the Content / File of this <see cref="MediaItem"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Url Source { get; set; }
    public Guid? SourceGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="Profile"/> entity that this media file is bound to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProfileGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="Article"/> entity that this media file is bound to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public Guid? ArticleGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="Communication.Comment"/> entity that this media file is bound to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public Guid? CommentGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="Theme"/> entity that this media file is bound to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }
    public Guid? ThemeGuid { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the entity inherits from the `SocialEntity` that holds a bunch of default collections. The `SocialEntity` then inherits the base `Entity` class with the Id, user, date created etc.

**Base class mapping**

```
CreateMap<SocialEntity, SocialDomainModel>()
       .IncludeBase<Entity, DomainModel>()
       .ReverseMap()
       .IncludeBase<DomainModel, Entity>();

CreateMap<Entity, DomainModel>()
       .IncludeBase<global::Data.Pattern.Entity.Entity, DomainModel>()
       .ReverseMap()
       .IncludeBase<DomainModel, global::Data.Pattern.Entity.Entity>();

CreateMap<global::Data.Pattern.Entity.Entity, DomainModel>()
       .ForMember(dm => dm.Creator, mo => mo.Ignore())
       .ForMember(dm => dm.CreatorGuid, mo => mo.Ignore())
       .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<MediaItem, Domain.Models.Storage.MediaItem>()
       .IncludeBase<SocialEntity, SocialDomainModel>()
       .ReverseMap()
       .IncludeBase<SocialDomainModel, SocialEntity>();
```

**The test method**

```
[TestMethod]
    public void MapMediaTest()
    {
        var m = MapperConfig.Mapper;

        var entity = new MediaItem();

        var entityToDomain = m.Map<Domain.Models.Storage.MediaItem>(entity);
        Assert.IsTrue(entityToDomain != null);
    }
```

**The result**
[image: Unit test memory usage]

As you can see, the memory floods after ~20 seconds.
It looks like automapper is configured wrong somewhere that causes an infinite loop and results in a `StackOverflowException`.

**My attempt**

- I've tried every single entity, always same result.
- Switched between 5.1.1 and 6.0.2 a bunch of times.
- Tried a lot of different configurations.
- Switched `HashSet` collections to normal `ICollections`.

I'm mapping between entities and domain models, no projection / querying used.
Every entity is retrieved before mapping, no lazy loading. 
Note, I do have `virtual` keywords with other entities and classes and every collection is initialized by default.


I'm out of options, I can't think of what to do besides ditching (not-so)AutoMapper for something else. I'd love some extra insight, thanks!

**Edit**
The `Article` class.

```
/// <summary>
///     Used to store <see cref="Article"/> data.
/// </summary>
[ResourceKey("ARTICLE")]
public class Article : SocialEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The main <see cref="Title"/> of this <see cref="Article"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The content <see cref="Body"/> of this <see cref="Article"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Body { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="ShortDescription"/> of this <see cref="Article"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The long <see cref="Description"/> of this <see cref="Article"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="DateTime"/> that the <see cref="Entity"/> will be available to use.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<Url> Sources { get; set; } = new HashSet<Url>();
    public virtual HashSet<MediaItem> Media { get; set; } = new HashSet<MediaItem>();
    public virtual HashSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new HashSet<Tag>();
    public virtual HashSet<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; } = new HashSet<Hobby>();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `IncludeBase` calls? I am pretty sure that is the default. And since you are calling `ReverseMap`, why are you creating reverse maps explicitly too

Comment: The `IncludeBase` calls are one of my many attempts to tackle this issue. To my understanding, the `ReverseMap` call makes sure that both-way mapping is initialized properly, I'd gladly remove them if these are now redundant.

Comment: Remove those and please make sure there are no circular dependencies either. Also to troubleshoot, start with one mapping and keep adding more until you see which mapping is the cause of the issue.

Comment: On it, i'll get back with the results soon. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alright, I've isolated most of the `CreateMapping` methods and the `StackOverflowException` started reoccurring when I add mapping for the `Article` class. I don't see how to proceed from this since I don't see any circular references.

Comment: what do those classes look like: The `Article` and the one it is being mapped to?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the `Article` class.

Comment: Are you sure `MediaItem`, `Tag` and `Hobby` are not referencing one of the other classes which are in turn referencing the `Article` class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144881/discussion-between-raybbo-and-codingyoshi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Richard's answer got me on the right track! Too many navigational properties...
AutoMapper couldn't figure out how to map them all, probably missing configurations. 

Entity Framework didn't have any problem with them, just AutoMapper.

I removed most of the navigational properties and it seemed that I didn't need most of them. This solved my issue the quick & easy way!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Automapper, you get StackOverflowException when mapping circular references.

I can see that MediaItem has an "Article" property, and Article has a collection of MediaItems.

If your Domain models also have equivalents of these navigation properties, do you need them both ways?

Comment: Yes, It should be possible with automapper. Seems like `MaxDepth(2)` isn't working properly.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had a structure like this in my system (both DTO and entity models were the same). There were lists of plans and only in some of them it would throw StackOverflowException. Entity Framework was doing fine having multiple levels of nesting like this, but AutoMapper would fail at ~3 levels. Fortunately the PreviousPlan property was not needed so I just removed it and it worked fine. If you can't afford removing it I would suggest playing with Automapper's MaxDepth.

I know it's not really an answer but maybe will help somebody find the cause.

```
public class Plan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousPlanId { get; set; }
    public Plan PreviousPlan { get; set; }
    ...
}
```